# Show that the finite complement topology is not Hausdorff.

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be the finite complement topology for an infinite set $X$. Let $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$, and let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$.

Why does every proof state that $X- U$ is finite? Is this because every finite subset of $X$ in a $T_{1}$ space is closed?

Apologies for my poor set theory knowledge!

Comment: If $U$ is non-empty open set in this topology then $X\setminus U$ is finite. Not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Mark I think his confusion comes from the fact that neighbourhood doesn't necessary mean open.

Comment: @N. S. It depends on what definitions OP is using. I always think of a neighborhood as of an open set, but I know in some books it is defined a bit different.

Comment: @Mark I overlooked the definition of the topology. Thanks for the reminder. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The finite complement topology is the topology in $X$ for which the open sets are precisely the empty set and the complements of finite sets. If $X$ is infinite.

A neighborhood $U$ of a point, by definition, $\textit{contains}$ an open set that contains the point. That open set can't be empty because it contains the point, therefore it is the complement of a finite set, i.e. there are only a finite number of points not in that open set.

But the points that are not in $U$ are also not in the open set contained in $U$. Therefore there are also only finitely many of those, i.e., $X-U$ is finite.

Comment: I understand now. Since the neighborhood $U$ is open, it must be in the topology $\mathcal{T}$ by definition. Since it is not empty, then its complement $X-U$ is finite. Thanks!

Comment: Careful: The neighborhood $U$ is not necessarily open, but it must $\textit{contain}$ an open set, which is enough to imply the result.

Comment: Also, keep in mind that N. S.'s answer formulates exactly what I said in the way that these things are supposed to be written, which is really important.

Comment: Interesting... the textbook I am using defines the neighborhood of a point $p$ in a topological space to be a subset of the underlying set that is open and contains $p$.

Comment: Alright, that's fair. I don't think that's the usual definition, but as long as it's consistent, it should be fine. Just keep in mind that it can be different elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up! I'll definitely be more careful.

Comment: In the finite complement topology, the two contending definitions of a "neighborhood of $p$" turn out to be equivalent! Given a subset $U \subset X$, $U$ is an open set containing $p$ if and only if $U$ contains an open set containing $p$ (this is a rare situation in topology, but it's true in the finite complement topology!)

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of $\tau$, $V$ open means that $V= \emptyset$ or $X \backslash V$ is finite.

Now, if $U$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, there exists an open set $V$ such that 
$$x \in V \subset U$$

Since $x \in V$ we have $V \neq \emptyset$, therefore $X \backslash V$ is finite.

Now, $V \subset U \Rightarrow$
$$X \backslash U \subset X \backslash V$$